# Stuck on connection to WSDL in VS2019

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have tried what seems like a million ways, and I might have confused myself to the point of too much frustration. I am very much a beginner in terms of WSDL. Ran through a calculator tutorial.
The task at hand is connecting to a WSDL Webservice from a Danish state department. (since the addresses are publicly available, so I see no reason to hide them.)
I have confirmed that the Soap webservice is working and is functional by using SoapUI 5.5.0, by following a guide from the department.
To begin with what I have been trying to do is create a very simple console application with hardcoded information, just to test out the C# code / the workflow. The final product is either going to be a MVC .Net or Blazor server.
I have removed the Username and password from the code and the request information which is a 10 digit code in string format. They have been replaced with ".....".

This Is the wsdl address: https://ws.fvst.dk/service/CHR_dyrWS?WSDL

All the information I have gathered. The steps for using a webservice is adding it via connected services and instantiating it, adding user information and calling the request function in the webservice and lastly fixing the config to using authentication.
But no matter what I do it seems like I cannot make it work, it throws a validation error or a Security.MessageSecurityException.

The code I currently have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ConsoleApp5.ServiceReference1;



namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            CHR_dyrWSClient client = new CHR_dyrWSClient();
            var basicHttpBinding = new  BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =  HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ".....";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ".....";

ServiceReference1.CHR_dyrHentCkrOplysningerRequest requestInfo = new ServiceReference1.CHR_dyrHentCkrOplysningerRequest();        
            requestInfo.Request.CkrNr = ".....";
            var responseInfo = client.hentCkrOplysninger(requestInfo);
            Console.WriteLine(responseInfo.Response);
            client.Close();
       }
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <basicHttpsBinding>
              <binding name="CHR_dyrWSPortBinding">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
              </binding>
            </basicHttpsBinding>
      </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint 
                address="https://ws.fvst.dk:443/service/CHR_dyrWS"
                binding="basicHttpsBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="CHR_dyrWSPortBinding" 
                contract="ServiceReference1.CHR_dyrWS"
                name="CHR_dyrWSPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I would really like to know where I need to go from here. I am really unsure if I’m connecting to the webservice wrong? The thing that I am most unsure about is the way you need to connect to this web service.

Any help or links would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I needed to send the optional information in the soap request too.
and i needed to specify a header in the app.config file.

To make it work i copied to header information from SoapUI in the http log.
Pasted it in the header information in the app.config. The username token can be removed and will still work.

[The entire program code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLGJv.png)

[Config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsJFU.png)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWMCT.png)